# XPATH Expression to Select Parent With Two Children Which Have Children

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML structure similar to this:

```
<Header>
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB>
            <ElementC/>
            <ElementC/>
        </ElementB>
        <ElementB/>
    </ElementA>
</Header>
```

where the `<ElementB>` may have a sequence of `<ElementC>`, or may have none.

I can select `<ElementA>` nodes which have two `<ElementB>` by `/Header/ElementA/ElementB/following-sibling::ElementB`. I can select `<ElementA>` nodes which contain an `<ElementB>` node which contains an `<ElementC>` using `/Header/ElementA/ElementB[ElementC]`.

But how do I select `<ElementA>` nodes which contain an `<ElementB>` which contains an `<ElementC>` followed by another `<ElementB>` containing another `<ElementC>`. Something like this:

```
<Header>
    <ElementA>
        <ElementB>
            <ElementC/>
            <ElementC/>
        </ElementB>
        <ElementB>
            <ElementC/>
            <ElementC/>
        </ElementB>
    </ElementA>
</Header>
```

Comment: @John-Saunders: You could probably show some respect and select the best answer (I think it is obviously the one by @Robert-Rossney).

Comment: @Dimitre: it would show the most respect if I accepted an answer after understanding it. I'm close, and I haven't forgotten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you don't have to explicitly search the following-sibling axis.  These two patterns will return the same result:

```
foo[bar/following-sibling::bar]
```

and

```
foo[bar[2]]
```

So your pattern can be as simple as:

```
/Header/ElementA[ElementB[ElementC][2]]
```

which will find `ElementA` elements that have two or more `ElementB` children, each of which has an `ElementC` child.

Comment: Very nice. One quibble: You probably don't need the predicate on `ElementC[2]` because he didn't specify that more than one `ElementC` be present, even though his example shows more than one.

Comment: +1 Best answer. If there are **at least two**, then there is a second. All of this **don't taking proximity** into the count.

Comment: In case you want to restrict selection to `foo`s with exactly two children `bar` use `//foo[count(bar)=2]`.

Answer (score 3):

I may just have answered my own question:

```
/Header/ElementA[ElementB[ElementC]/following-sibling::ElementB[ElementC]]
```

seems to work. The reason it didn't appear to work before is that my document, all 88,000 lines of it, had no occurrence of that pattern. This probably indicates a bug in the code that produces it, not a bug in my XPATH expression.

Comment: @John-Saunders: You could probably show some respect and select the best answer (I think it is obviously the one by @Robert-Rossney).

Answer (score 2):

A nested predicate gets the job done:

```
/Header/ElementA[ElementB[following-sibling::ElementB/ElementC]/ElementC]
```